# rails 3.2 jquery ui not working

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I 'm trying to get Jquery-UI working and having a tough time getting it to work. I did read [this](http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/jquery-ui-css-and-images-and-rails-asset-pipeline/) article about using jquery UI with ROR. I have also copied the images to app/stylesheets/images. I can't get the datepicker widget or jqueryUI styled textbox working. Any suggestions on what I 'm missing?

**Application.js**

```
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui.min
//= require jquery_ujs
```

**Application.css**

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css
 *= require_self
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Comment: The [gem documentation](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) states that you should have `//= require jquery.ui.all` in your `application.js`, not `//= require jquery-ui.min`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

*application.html.erb*

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js","jquery-rails.js"%>
```

*application.js*

```
$(function() {
  $("#book_published_on").datepicker();
});
```

*new.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @books do |f| %>
Name :<%= f.text_field :name %><br />
Publish date :<%= f.text_field :published_on %><br></div>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

no need to add any additional gems. default gem *'jquery-rails'* is enough